# How to show absolute element inside the overflow hidden parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got as following:

```
<div parent-with-overflow-hidden>
  <div absolute-position></div>
</div>
```

The real context is using the drop down menu bootstrap

```
<div overflow-hidden>
  <div class="dropdown">
     <button>Click to show menu</button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">Menu</ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

that I cannot show entire the `menu`.

How can I display the child div without move it outside the parent?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the CSS you have for these elements?

Comment: @RyanHipkiss My case looks like below Mihai comment

Answer (score 3):

using `position:absolute` won't get it out of the parent with `overflow-hidden` . so you need to overwrite that with `position:fixed` . it will get the `.dropdown-menu` out of any parent/grandparent it has.

then you need to set the `top` position depending on the `height` of the parent, which is the `overflow-hidden` div.

after that, you need to dynamically re-calculate the `top` position while scrolling the page so that the dropdown stays in the same position

let me know if it works ;)

see **snippet**  below or fiddle > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/26593/)

```js
    var oHeight = $('.ohidden ').height()
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('top',oHeight)

 
 //dropdown remain `glued` to the button on scroll
 
 $(window).on("scroll",function(){
    var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop()
    $('.dropdown-menu').css('top',oHeight-wScroll)

})
```

```css
.ohidden { overflow:hidden}
.dropdown-menu { position:fixed!important;}
body { height:2000px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="ohidden">
  <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
  Click to show Menu
 </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ITEM 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai for your idea. But I think this way has many work to do and perhaps reduce performance. All I want just simpler. Put another way, just piece of code.

Comment: well.. this is very simple. and , in my oppinion, it's the best way to do this